# Solve $a\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+by\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+c\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, nonlinear-analysis

Is there any specific method of solving nonlinear differential equations? I want to solve the following differential $$a\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+by\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+c\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
by the method of undetermined coefficients, but getting a term like $am^3e^{mx} + bm^2e^{2mx} + cme^{mx} = 0$. Please give some suggestions to solve.

Comment: I do not immediately have an answer to how to solve this problem, however I have two comments.  Firstly, there is no specific method which works for solving all nonlinear differential equations.  Power series solutions are probably the closest to this, but they have their drawbacks.  The other methods are usually algebraic, involving clever substitutions (of which I am looking for right now).  Secondly, method of undetermined coefficients is for nonhomogeneous equations, so your method of solution shouldn't involve it.

Comment: @mildboson thanks for the comment, please suggest some substitution.

Answer (score 2):

$$a\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+by\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+c\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
The DE is not linear so you can't use usual tricks for linear DE. Maybe you can reduce the order of the de. Substitute:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=p \text { and } p'=\dfrac {dp}{dy}$$=
$$ap\dfrac d{dy}(pp')+bypp'+cp=0$$
$$ap(p'^2+pp'')+bypp'+cp=0$$
Note that $y=C$ is a solution of the original DE. Then:
$$a(p'^2+pp'')+byp'+c=0$$